# data manipulation with pandas date_range object

Tags: python, pandas

New to Pandas. I have a list  L that is associated with date, now I want to get a subset of L based on input time range.

e.g,    L is a list of 365 elements ordered by date, i.e,  one year data based on days.

```
date = pandas.date_range(start = '1/1/2013', end = '12/31/2013', freq='D')
desiredDate = pandas.date_range(start = '4/2/2013', end = '6/5/2013', freq='D')
```

How to get a list of select elements from L with those specified desiredDate?

what I am thinking is to get 2 dates obj, one with start = 1/1, but end date = 4/2/2013, find out its length. 
another is with start = 1/1, but end date = 6.5, find out its length again. Then this problem might be solved. If someone knows some Pandas library function to solve this in a more elegant way, please reply, thanks

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

From what I've seen, `pandas` index objects support the same membership methods as python `set()` objects, such as intersection, union, difference, and symmetric difference.   Try using the intersection operator (`&`) on the two DatetimeIndex objects.

```
In [9]: date = pandas.date_range(start = '1/1/2013', end = '12/31/2013', freq='D')

In [10]: desiredDate = pandas.date_range(start = '4/2/2013', end = '6/5/2013', freq='D')

In [11]: date & desiredDate
Out[11]: 
<class 'pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex'>
[2013-04-02, ..., 2013-06-05]
Length: 65, Freq: D, Timezone: None

In [12]: len(desiredDate)
Out[12]: 65

In [13]: len(date & desiredDate)
Out[13]: 65
```